# Function pointer problem in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, function-pointers

So I am trying to store a series of methods in an array (if that made sense).

```
void *pointer[3];
pointer[0] = &[self rotate];
pointer[1] = &[self move];
pointer[2] = &[self attack];
//...
```

What I am trying to do is have an array of stuff and based on the type of the object in the array, a certain method is invoked. And instead of having a bunch of if statement saying something like:

```
if ([[myArray objectAtIndex:0] type] == robot]) {
     //Do what robots do...
}
else if (...) {
}
else {
}
```

And having this in a timer I was hoping to make it something like this:

```
pointer[[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] type]]; //This should invoke the appropriate method stored in the pointer.
```

Right now the code above says (the very first block of code):

> Lvalue required as unary '&' operand.

If you need any clarification just ask.

Also, just to let you know all the method I am calling are type void and don't have any parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function pointers if you need to pass around references to C functions but when working with methods on Objective-C objects you should really use [selectors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html) and the `SEL` type.

Your code would then be something like:

```
SEL selectors[3];
selectors[0] = @selector(rotate);
selectors[1] = @selector(move);
selectors[2] = @selector(attack);

...

[self performSelector:selectors[n]];
```

Comment: I have ran your code. It should be selector[3] not *selector[3], but thanks!

Comment: Oops, good catch. That's what I get for copy-past-editing without testing it. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You can't just make a function pointer out of an Objective-C function using the `&` Operator.

You'll want to look into:

- [@selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html)
- [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Any of these can do what you want. Definitely read about selectors (the `@selector` compiler directive and the `SEL` type) if you're unfamiliar with that (it's a basic concept that you'll need a lot). Blocks are fairly new (available since Mac OS X 10.6 and iOS 4) and they'll save you a ton of work where you would have needed target/selector, NSInvocation or callback functions on earlier versions of Mac OS X and iOS.